# Why is there a prefix/postfix ++ but no prefix/postfix +=?

Tags: java, c++, c, operators

This may seem like a silly question, but why is it that in many languages there exists a prefix and postfix version of the `++` and `--` operator, but no similar prefix/postfix versions of other operators like `+=` or `-=`?  For example, it seems like if I can write this code:

```
myArray[x++] = 137; // Write 137 to array index at x, then increment x
```

I should be able to write something like

```
myArray[5 =+ x] = 137; // Write 137 to array index at x, then add five to x
```

Of course, such an operator does not exist.  Is there a reason for this?  It seems like a weird asymmetry in C/C++/Java.

Comment: So, basically, you ask why is it allowed only for the special case of ±1?

Comment: Personally, I am in favor of the `myArray[x++++++++++++++++++++] = 137;` syntax.

Comment: @pst Or how about `myArray[x.plusPlus(10)] = 137;`

Comment: @templatetypedef : I think, this looks better >> `myArray[x=+5] = 137;` (post addition) ... and the existing one >> `myArray[x+=5] = 137;` (pre addition).... the idea is, keep `x` always on the left side!

Comment: Should `x=-1` be parsed as `x =- 1` or as `x = -1`? :)

Comment: I addressed this below.  That was just a suggestion, of course, and the actual syntax could be totally different.

Comment: @pst: `x++++` is illegal, because the expression `x++` is an rvalue, but the `++` operator requires an lvalue as its operand.

Comment: @quinmars: General rules of token parsing are: be context insensitive, take the longest token possible when confronted with a choice: x=-1 is thus three token x =- 1. This is why we had the trouble with vector<vector<int>> The double '>>' was tokenized as the right shift operator. Which is why C++ tokenizer is now context sensitive (which is exceedingly rare for computer languages) to compensate.

Comment: @FredOverflow Not when it's added to Java 8 or C# 42 specification ;-) I believe Perl *could* get away with it in a post-decrement (the thing it returns isn't really a value afaik -- or what that a pre-decrement?), in any case when I tried I get a "non-syntax" error along the lines "can't modify pre/post decrement in pre/post decrement" which I *believe* is happening as an AST guard later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd guess there are several reasons, I think among the more heavily weighted might be:

- there probably weren't thought to be too many real use cases (it may not have even occurred to some language designers in the early days)
- pre/post increment mapped directly to machine operations (at least on several machines), so they found their way into the language (update: it turns out that this isn't exactly true, even if it's commonly thought so in computing lore.  See below).

Then again, while the idea for pre/post/increment/decrement operators might have been influenced by machine operations, it looks like they weren't put into the language specifically to take advantage of such. Here's what Dennis Ritchie has to say about them:

http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html

> Thompson went a step further by inventing the ++ and -- operators, which increment or decrement; their prefix or postfix position determines whether the alteration occurs before or after noting the value of the operand. They were not in the earliest versions of B, but appeared along the way. People often guess that they were created to use the auto-increment and auto-decrement address modes provided by the DEC PDP-11 on which C and Unix first became popular. This is historically impossible, since there was no PDP-11 when B was developed. The PDP-7, however, did have a few `auto-increment' memory cells, with the property that an indirect memory reference through them incremented the cell. This feature probably suggested such operators to Thompson; the generalization to make them both prefix and postfix was his own. Indeed, the auto-increment cells were not used directly in implementation of the operators, and a stronger motivation for the innovation was probably his observation that the translation of ++x was smaller than that of x=x+1.

Answer (score 4):

As long as `y` has no side effects:

```
#define POSTADD(x,y) (((x)+=(y))-(y))
```

Comment: Or with some side-effect safety in C++: `template <typename T, typename U> T postadd( T& x, U increment) { T tmp = x; x = x + increment; return tmp; }`  But I'd strongly recommend to avoid using something like this (if there's a good reason for using it, I'd like to hear the justification - it might be interesting).

Answer (score 2):

I'll make an assumption. There're lots of use-cases for `++i`/`i++` and in many the specific type of increment (pre/post) makes difference. I can't tell how many times I've seen code like `while (buf[i++]) {...}`. On the other hand, `+=` is used much less frequently, as it rarely makes sense to shift pointer by 5 elements at once.

So, there's just no common enough application where difference between postfix and prefix version of `+=` would be important.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because it's way too cryptic.
Some argue that even ++/-- should be avoided, because they cause confusion and are responsible for most buffer overrun bugs.

Comment: I use postfix ++ (and less often --) only and only in for loops.

Comment: @Goran: That's great for C, but not so much for C++ (where postfix operations on iterators can be quite expensive).

Comment: "Some argue that even ++/-- should be avoided, because they cause confusion and are responsible for most buffer overrun bugs.":  I don't buy that argument.  It's not the `++` or `--`, it's failure to pay attention to the length of the buffer.  `+=` won't help you avoid a buffer overflow if you don't pay attention to the length of the buffer.

Comment: @Max Lybbert: I think that the arguments tries to state that for (; n > 0; --n) *dst++ = *src++; is not a style one should use.

Comment: There are a lot of things to avoid, but that doesn't say anything about the merits of `++` and `--`. My copy of The C Programming Language goes through a lot of effort explaining why while `(*src++ = *dest++) ;` copies null-terminated strings (and claiming that any C programmer should understand it, even if they don't use that style).  The example given works fine if both `dst` and `src` are at least `n` items long.  It fails only when the programmer isn't paying attention to the lengths of the buffers, and switching to `+=` and `-=` doesn't make the code any better.

Answer (score 1):

Because the -- and ++ operators map to `inc`(rement) and `dec`(rement) instructions (in addition to adding and subtracting) in the CPU, and these operators are *supposed* to map to the instructions, hence why they exist as separate operators.

Comment: But this is only true for one processor architecture, right?  I don't remember seeing this anywhere in MIPS, for example.

Comment: Yeah, it's true for some, the one I know of being x86.

Comment: @templatetypedef: The PDP-11 is just a little bit older than MIPS and C was originally written to work with the PDP-11. Everyone else has pre- and post- increment and decrement operators because C has them.

Answer (score 1):

Java and C++ have pre- and post- increment and decrement operators because C has them. C has them because C was written, mostly, for the PDP-11 and the PDP-11 had `INC` and `DEC` instructions.

Back in the day, optimizing compilers didn't exist so if you wanted to use a single cycle increment operator, either you wrote assembler for it or your language needed an explicit operator for it; C, being a portable assembling language, has explicit increment and decrement operators. Also, the performance difference between `++i` and `i++` rarely matters now but it did matter in 1972.

Keep in mind that C is almost 40 years old.

Comment: However, a startling number of SO/web questions still seem to relate to the "performance" of `i++` vs `++i` vs `i = i + 1` ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it's common to equate:

`x += 5;`

...with:

`x = x + 5;`

And for obvious reasons, it would be nonsensical to write:

`x + 5 = x;`

I'm not sure how else you would mimic the behavior of `5 =+ x` using just the `+` operator. By the way, hi htiek!

Comment: Clearly it's possible. In the case of `x + 5 = x` it can be shown that `5 = 0` with the subtraction of `x` from both sides. QED. ;-)